# When does local search algorithm for SMT (1-Steiner algorithm) not output the optimal solution?

Tags: optimization, heuristics, local-search

I am trying to find an example where the 1-steiner algorithm (local search algorithm for Steiner Minimum Tree) does not output the optimal solution, but each instance I find seems to be optimal.

Comment: Do you mean [this algorithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221799001319) here?

What do your code looks like? like [this](https://github.com/gualt1995/pRP)?